# resources for image analysis of test sheets (Choice test) (Scanned pictures)?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm developing and application for a learning company. I need to image analysis of Test sheet (scanned) and analysis the answer of students. 
  Answer sheets are like this picture :
[image: test answer sheet]

there are 4 options for every test. 
I think there is components ready for that. I searched a lot and find different image processing stuffs but nothing about this one.
Where can I find tutorial or information or component for this? I mean any good website or source to start learning the solutions?
I'm using Delphi but I can change it to C# if it is Necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: use edgedetector like Canny to detect the edges...use findContour to select the largest block as shown in green below...make that the region of interest or ROI for future processing..[image: green edge]

Step 2: Take **TWO** template of the square (where students are supposed to tick or darken)..one representing ticked/darkened other one just a blank square...run a template matching of those two templates in the ROI to get possible positions of the answers.

Step 3: since the layout of the answer sheet is supposed to be constant so you can grid the answer sheet before and use it as prior knowledge to map the template match locations to actual answers.[image]